# Residual values in template formset fields with modelformset

Tags: django, django-models, formset

I use modelformset_factory with an object named selection in a view function named spectacle. Every item gets saved. But after that, the page gets loaded
with the previous items. Such an unsuspected behaviour.

What did I miss ? Is it something with the validation ?

Here the summed-up code :

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory

def spectacle(request, id_spectacle=0):

selections_formset = modelformset_factory(Selection, fields=('nom',), extra=1)
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = selections_formset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        for selection_form in formset:
            selection_from_formset = selection_form.save(commit=False)
            if selection_from_formset.nom != "" and selection_from_formset.nom is not None :
                selection_from_formset.save()
        message = 'success'
        for fs in formset:
            print fs.cleaned_data
    else:
        message = 'fail'
    return render(request, 'create_spectacle.html',
                  {"formset": equipes_formset
                   })
else:
    return render(request, 'create_spectacle.html',
                      {"formset": equipes_formset
                       })


<div id="my_form">
<form action="{% url 'create_spectacle' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<div id="formsetZone">
    {% for form in formset %}
        <div class="nformset_form">
            <h3>Equipe</h3>
            {{ form.as_p }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating the form with POST data (to save it). 
Then rendering the same formset with the same POST data. This is useful for displaying errors, but in case of success, not what you want

The standard pattern is to save the form / formset, (then assuming no errors) redirect. in Your case redirect to a GET version of the form.

before the first "else" add something like

```
        return HttpResponseRedirect("add the url to your view here")
```

It will then run the same code, but without the POST data. Alternatively, add a different url to a success page.

Here is the example in the docs (for a single form, but its the same principle):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/#the-view

You are missing the line:

```
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder but
though it works with other fields outside of the formset (that I didn't mention to simplify), it does not work for the formset.
The redirection works well and generates a get request but the formset fields appear filled with the revious values.
It seems to have something to do with the second line : selections_formset = modelformset_factory(Selection, fields=('nom',), extra=1)